# Installing R on EC2 RHEL 7

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, rhel7

Has anyone had any luck on the AWS/EC2 RHEL 7.2?

I ran `sudo yum install -y epel-release` to get access to the EPEL packages.
Next I tried `sudo yum install R` but it fails with:

`Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.3.1-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: texinfo-tex`

I saw people mentioning for that you need to allow optional packages to get `texinfo-tex`, but none of that seems to work on AWS.  For example, I tried this to no avail: `sudo yum --enablerepo=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms install R`

If I try: `sudo yum --skip-broken install R` then it fails with this message:

`Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    GConf2-3.2.6-8.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    R-3.3.1-1.el7.x86_64 from epel
    R-core-3.3.1-1.el7.x86_64 from epel
    R-core-devel-3.3.1-1.el7.x86_64 from epel
    R-devel-3.3.1-1.el7.x86_64 from epel
    R-java-devel-3.3.1-1.el7.x86_64 from epel
    bzip2-devel-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    flac-libs-1.3.0-5.el7_1.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    gcc-gfortran-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    gsm-1.0.13-11.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.111-2.6.7.2.el7_2.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.111-2.6.7.2.el7_2.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.111-2.6.7.2.el7_2.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    libasyncns-0.8-7.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    libicu-devel-50.1.2-15.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    2:libogg-1.3.0-7.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    libquadmath-devel-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    libsndfile-1.0.25-10.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    1:libvorbis-1.3.3-8.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    pcre-devel-8.32-15.el7_2.1.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    pcsc-lite-libs-1.8.8-6.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    psmisc-22.20-9.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    pulseaudio-libs-6.0-7.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    1:tcl-devel-8.5.13-8.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    1:tk-devel-8.5.13-6.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
    tre-devel-0.8.0-10.el7.x86_64 from epel
    xz-devel-5.1.2-12alpha.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases`

It must be something simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What did `--list` say on the answer I gave earlier?

Comment: If I do: `sudo subscription-manager repos --list` then I get: `This system has no repositories available through subscriptions.`.  One thing that I've seen mentioned is modifying `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/subscription-manager.conf` to toggle `enabled`, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: This is very unusual *but* I have found precedence of this problem on AWS. The related threads went on for months with people trying to solve it unsuccessfully, asides from one case which I will describe in an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I saw some of these threads for RHEL 5* and 6* here and none of that worked.  R is fairly popular, it seems weird that it shouldn't just work...

Comment: For what it's worth it works fine on non-AWS for me. I've installed and run R on RHEL 7 at work.

Comment: Yeah, just seems really strange.  It finds all the other packages but not this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try, I have a feeling it will solve some of your problems:

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional
```

I probably have this feeling because we figured it out together in chat :)

Apparently someone ran into this issue and solved it when installing a package called Kaltura:

https://thomas-barthelemy.github.io/2015/03/19/ec2-epel-rhel7/

Comment: Worked.  I have no idea why.  But now everything is installing perfectly.

Comment: @JoshK We just had to try everything in every tangentially related Google result. Simple.

Comment: @akrun That's not true. This answer is totally different. The OP and I were working in chat together on this and after 30 - 60min after the prior answer and he and I came up with this. The prior answer worked for RHEL in general but not his EC2 situation.. There was also serial downvoting going on but I still would've edited the same answer but this is entirely different than the prior answer. I thought that you appreciated me not mentioning you by name in that Meta question and appreciated the nice things I said about you and the comments I deleted at your request and had moved on...